# Custom ItemControl for ListBox

Tags: wpf, listbox, custom-controls, listboxitem

I want to add new DependencyProperty to ListBoxItem class which used in ListBox control. I need to add IsEditing property. When user will does long click on my ListBoxItem I will change it IsEditing property to True and then in Trigger of this property will be style changing. Actually the idea to change TextBlock to TextBox in style.

I hope my explanation is clear. Does it make any sense, or there is exist more simple way?

Thanks

Comment: how do you ascertain 'long click'?

Comment: I will override OnButtonDown and start timer, if control lost focus or OnButtonUp raised - the timer is stops. If nothing else happens - will raise timer.tick. smth like that

Comment: How can I set to ListBox another derived from ListBoxItem class? I want ListBox use my ListBoxItem class

Answer (score 0):

See the XAML below - A child of DataTemplate is your item's template. You can use built-in WPF elements like Grid, Canvas etc. or your own user/custom control. You can create EditableItem control and use it to handle long mouse clicks etc.

This is not the most elegant way of doing this, but probably the simplest one. The more advanced approach would involve the usage of attached behaviors, which elliminates need for custom/user controls. Also, look at VisualStateManager class, it'll simplify switching between different 'modes' of your editable item (that's what I'd use for it anyway).

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <ListBox x:Name="l">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="30" Background="Green" Width="100">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += (o, e) => 
            {
                this.l.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 3);
            };
        }
    }
}
```